# How to get message from other thread winapi

Tags: c++, winapi

I need to run message loop in other thread using `std::async`, is it possible to get messages from main thread? Can you give some exampels?

And second question: i do not need to call `wndproc`, what i need is just getting messages and avoid "program not responding", do i need to call `dispatchmessage()`?

Comment: _",,,The system does not automatically create a message queue for each thread. Instead, the system creates a message queue only for threads that perform operations which require a message queue.,,,"_ have a read of: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-messages-and-message-queues

Comment: What's the real problem you are trying to solve? You have asked about your proposed solution. That's commonly known as the [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).

Comment: "*what i need is just getting messages and avoid "program not responding"*" - that requires the *owning thread* of the UI to actively retrieve UI messages via `(Get|Peek)Message()` and dispatch them via `DispatchMessage()` in a timely manner, yes.

Comment: You need to share the specific problem you want to solve. Perhaps you only want to monitor the main thread messages, you can use [hook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa) to get message with `WH_CALLWNDPROC` or `WH_CALLWNDPROCRET`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each thread manages its own message queue.  If you want the main thread's messages, the main thread must get them and post them to you. But it sounds like that would defeat the purpose altogether.

Sounds like what you really want is to switch your threads' places.  Have the main thread run your message pump and do your intensive processing on another thread.

As for `DispatchMessage`, you can get by without it if you don't have a window. But if you do, you should call it.  You have to handle window messages in order to appear responsive, and it hides some of the details of doing so.